# Django Get whole filepath after upload

Tags: python, django

I'm building my first project with Django and I've some trouble with the filepath. I use a model to store the information to a db and pass get some fields/metadata from views e.g. size, filename,...

My problem is now that Django automatically renames the file, if there is already a file with a similiar name. That's okay. But I don't find a way, how I can store the new name and filepath in my database.

initial_obj.file.url just gives me "/media/filename.txt" but the right path is: "media/userfiles/2019/11/10/filename_1nswmaP.txt"

views.py

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            initial_obj = UploadModel(file = request.FILES['file'])
            initial_obj.status = 'Übermittelt'
            initial_obj.uploaded_by = request.user.username
            initial_obj.filename = initial_obj.file.name
            initial_obj.filesize = initial_obj.file.size
            initial_obj.filepath = initial_obj.file.url
            initial_obj.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render(request, 'upload/fileupload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings

class UploadModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='userfiles/%Y/%m/%d/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True) 
    uploaded_by =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices = [("Fertig", "Fertig"),("Übermittelt","Übermittelt"),("In Bearbeitung","In Bearbeitung"),("Support","Support")])
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=999)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    filesize = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: The `.url` is the item you pass to the *webpage*, such that a user can fetch the image.

Comment: I also tried `.path` but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

While the file is not saved yet, the system can only get the path from the temporary file. Therefore `initial_obj.file.url` has to be stored in a var after the first `initial_obj.save()` and then you can save another time.